# Is it possible to sell chrome extension as of Aug 2020?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to find a way to sell a chrome extension with one-time payment, but I can't find monetizing settings in chrome webstore developer console(neither in new nor old dashbord provide those options). It just says "Adding new in-app products is disabled until further notice" but are one-time payment products also being suspended as of Aug 2020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot currently sell an extension using the Chrome Web Store's payments service, you can do so using 3rd party platforms. I'd recommend looking into at 3rd party payment service providers. I'm most familiar with Stripe, PayPal, Chargebee, and Amazon Pay but there are a ton of other options out there.

Comment: Thank you Simeon, but I'm in another trouble. Following your answer, I thought to code like this: 1. make user pay on 3rd party payment service 2. email them activation code 3. make user activate chrome app with activation code.  But the problem is in the process 3: activation code is meaningless in this situation because there's no serverside. Do you have some good idea for this situation?

Comment: @Keisuke could you try an approach like how old software licenses used to work, where they follow some sort of cryptographic hash, or in other words, like a string that follows a particular pattern?  I've never developed one, but that might get you researching in the right direction.  Heck, even something braindead like a particular pattern with checksum at the end might be a temporary hack for now while Chrome webstore is not being supported due to covid.  You'd probably have to obfuscate that part of your code also. :-)

Comment: @KeisukeNagakawa any updates? What did you do? I have the same "problem".

Answer (score 0):

I've find a post that says:

> Blockquote
> Chrome Web Store payments - We are disabling the ability to create new paid items or add payments to existing items. This includes extensions, themes, apps, and in-app purchases.

So it seems that there's no way to sell extensions for now.

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/r5EKL-McE3A/m/qcGlI0HXAQAJ